# Returning a functools.partial from a function accepting any arguments

Tags: python, functools

I need to create a mock-method that stores any arguments passed to it, so I can later assert it was called correctly. To do that I need to create functions from the mock-objects store function, so that I can return anything I want but store all parameters. The MWE of what I am trying to do looks like this:

```
import functools
f1 = lambda test, *a, **b: print(a, b, test)
f2 = functools.partial(f1, test=42)
f2(2,3,a=4)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() got multiple values for argument 'test'
```

Is it possible to get this working? In essence I need `f2` to accept any number of positional or keyword_arguments, but have the argument `test` already defined as input for `f1`.

I want the above call to `f2` print:

```
(2, 3) {'a': 4} 42
```

or similar, it's important that `test` can be used in `f1` but doesn't have to be set/is already predefined for `f2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
import functools
f1 = lambda test, *a, **b: print(a, b, test)
f2 = functools.partial(f1, 42)
f2(2, 3, a=4)
```

output:

```
(2, 3) {'a': 4} 42
```

Note that using lambda in this case is not in line with [PEP8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#toc-entry-38). Use regular function instead:

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that
> binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier:

```
# Correct: def f(x): return 2*x
 
# Wrong: f = lambda x: 2*x
```

> The first form means that the name of the resulting function object is
> specifically 'f' instead of the generic ''. This is more
> useful for tracebacks and string representations in general. The use
> of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda
> expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can
> be embedded inside a larger expression)

Comment: Ahh, so using test as a kwarg tripped it up. Yeah I only used the lambdas here for the MWE :)

Answer (score 1):

It works without using partial:

```
f1 = lambda test, *a, **b: print(a, b, test)
f2 = lambda *args, **kwargs: f1(42, *args, **kwargs)
f2(2,3,a=4)

# (2, 3) {'a': 4} 42
```